# Can we use Newtonsoft Json.net in Windows runtime component for universal apps

Tags: c#, json, windows-runtime, json.net, windows-10-universal

I have a requirement to build a windows runtime component so as to be reusable for building windows universal apps. In it there are quite some json manipulations that are needed to be done for which I am using newtonsoft json.net as we do that normally but later I noticed using this would create a dependency for app developer to add the same as reference to there windows app projects so as to use my component which I feel is an additional task for them (as some people might be using some other libraries for json parsing). So is there any way I can bundle the library with my component to avoid mentioning this dependency in the documentation for me.

Answer (score 0):

If you install the library using Nuget. Nuget will add the dependencies of this library to your project based on the package.json. If you want to bind the dependency library to your project. You can manually add the physical dll files as reference.
You can achieve this by following steps:

1. Add the Newtonsoft.Json Nuget Package to your project. Nuget will add the library to your local machine.
2. Add reference of `C:\Users\username\.nuget\packages\Newtonsoft.Json\versionNumber\lib\portable-net45+wp80+win8+wpa81\Newtonsoft.Json.dll` to your VS project.
3. Now the library is embedded to your project.

Comment: Thank you,I was actually doing the same, I have decided to replace newtonsoft parsing logic with windows core json parsing capability(using window.data.json) namespace...I actually wanted to just give the .winmd file to users and didn't want to give them the whole folder with all dependent references copied to the bin folder.